# Qt Desiger Wizard add new page

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to create a setup wizard with Qt, using Qt Designer. I see that it gives me a way to use a template while creating a new project. In the widget there is a section called "Wizard", and when I create the project from it, the result is a wizard with 2 pages, but I want it with 3. How could I add one more? The pages are displayed in the Object Inspector, but I am not able to find how to add one more. Any suggestions? I’d like to only use Designer, not other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with any other "page based" widget like QTabWidget or QStackedWidget, right click on an empty area of the widget (the wizard page, in this case) and add a new page from the "Insert" menu.